# NodeJS app as CLI tool

Tags: node.js, linux, command-line-interface

I have Ubuntu Linux and a CLI NodeJS app which I start with:

```
$ node myapp.js param1 value1 param2 value2
```

Now I want to start myapp.js like this:

```
$ myapp param1 value1 param2 value2
```

Comment: Look how to make a alias for `node myapp.js`, superuser may be a better place for this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a shebang to the beginning of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Copy to somewhere in your PATH (using /usr/local/bin as an example):

```
$ cp myapp.js /usr/local/bin/myapp
```

Finally, make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/myapp
```

Now your program can be run as:

```
$ myapp param1 value1 param2 value2
```

(If the program has dependencies, you will need to install them globally, with the `-g` flag)

Answer (score 2):

use [nexe](https://github.com/jaredallard/nexe) to convert your node script into binary which you can put in usr/local or any other folder which is added into your env variables so that you can run from commandline.

```
npm install nexe -g  

nexe -i ./myapp.js -o ./myapp
```

Comment: wow great, thank you. i was looking for a way to make my node app binary, too.